# Define multiple templates for a predefined block wagtail CRX

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I was moving a site over to wagtail and decided to use the [codered extensions](https://docs.coderedcorp.com/wagtail-crx/). The library comes with a image-gallery content-block. I want to use this but define a few templates you can choose from in the admin UI.

You usually define a template in the meta section, but I noticed a dropdown in the admin UI for a template.
How do I add a template to that dropdown? Link to [the content block I want to change](https://github.com/coderedcorp/coderedcms/blob/dev/coderedcms/blocks/content_blocks.py#L83)

I am interested in adding an HTML template and not inheriting from the content-block to change behaviour. (Unless inheriting is the only way to add a template to the dropdown.)

Comment: It seems this was added last year and is not documented well yet. The devs are also looking to ease/change the way it is meant to be used. See the following gh issue, I will try this tomorrow and close/answer this question if it works. https://github.com/coderedcorp/coderedcms/issues/476

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from Richard Allen works wagtail and is perfect for your own blocks etc. Wagtail blocks define a separate field that is used for their included components, for this you need another approach.

First you need to add the [CRX_FRONTEND_TEMPLATE_BLOCKS](https://github.com/coderedcorp/coderedcms/blob/dc99b22efd86d2218ad66de918222c59b79607d0/coderedcms/settings.py#L133) to your django settings `mysite/settings/base.py`.

Then create a folder for your block templates in `mysite/website/templates` and create a custom template. Then add this path as a entry to the CRX_FRONTEND_TEMPLATE_BLOCKS. Entry key should be the block in lowercase. For a starter you could copy a template/html file from the codered package, found in `coderedcms/blocks/`

Now the template should be available from the template dropdown under the advanced menu of a crx block.

This info came from a [gh issue](https://github.com/coderedcorp/coderedcms/issues/476) of crx. This is e pretty recent addition and the dev mentioned that they are looking to make this easier. So this might change in the future, this worked for me on 26/01/2023.

Answer (score 2):

You could paramatise the path to the template you want to use then use an `include` in your block template to point to the chosen one.

For example, if you had a card block with selection for vertical or horizontal format. In your card block class you might have an property named `template` that uses a choice block, something like

```
class AlignmentChoiceBlock(ChoiceBlock):
    choices=[
        ('blocks/flex/vertical_card.html', 'Vertical'), 
        ('blocks/flex/horizontal_card.html', 'Horizontal') 
    ]
```

Then in your block template, it just consists of:

```
<div class="some-block-container">
    {% include value.template %}
</div>
```

Well, this works for Wagtail at least, not sure about codered.

Comment: This is perfect for custom wagtail blocks thanks, for predefined crx blocks it's a bit different. So I changed the title to specify crx and added a specific solution for that.